# How to write this query in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following SQL query.

```
SELECT server, count(server)
FROM host 
WHERE host_id = 528
      AND server != '' AND server IS NOT NULL
      AND timestamp > '2015-03-08' AND timestamp < '2015-03-10'
GROUP BY server;
```

I tried writing it as

```
query = (models.Host.objects
    .values_list(server).filter(host_id=host.id,
    timestamp__gte=datetime.datetime.strptime(from_time,'%Y-%m-%d'),
    timestamp__lte=datetime.datetime.strptime(to_time, ''%Y-%m-%d'),
    server__isnull=False))
```

This is not working. Any helps please

Comment: put `.values_list(server)` in end of query

Comment: Does not show up anythiong

Comment: Did you get something by doing `.filter(host_id=host.id)` only?

Comment: try chaining the filters instead of writing the lookups in a single filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like after filter you need grouped data by server. Django have aggregation functionality, that do what you want:

```
from django.db.models import Count


query = models.Host.objects.filter(
    host_id=host.id, 
    timestamp__gt=datetime.datetime.strptime(from_time,'%Y-%m-%d'),
    timestamp__lt=datetime.datetime.strptime(to_time, '%Y-%m-%d'), 
    server__isnull=False).values('server').annotate(server_count=Count('server'))
```

[More about aggregation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/)

Some notes:

- django and sql queries are different (in sql you use great/less then, but in django - great/less **or equal** then)
- in your case better use [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#range): `timestamp__range=(from_time, to_time)`